# Why no result of db.database.find() although data is there in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, import, mongodb-query

I have imported data into mongodb from csv files which has a million records using mongoimport utility:

```
show dbs;
admin     0.000GB
ded       0.305GB
local     0.000GB
visitors  0.000GB
db.ded.find();
```

Why is there no rows in the ded database when there is data of 0.305GB?
How can I see this data?
Any inputs on this would be great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find()` does not return any document because you are using the `test` database which does not have collection named `ded`.

By default, MongoDB connects to the `test` database and from the output of `show dbs`, it clear that `ded` is a database. To query the documents in the collections in that database, you first need to switch to it using:

```
use ded
```

Then `show collections` to list the collections in that database.

Also note that after switching, `db` is the instance of your database (here `ded`) so you will be querying your collection like this:

```
db.collectionname.find()
```

So if your collection's name is "flights",

```
db.flights.find()
```

See [Working with the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#working-with-the-mongo-shell)

Comment: No see the output below it is not about use at all                                                          > show dbs;
admin       0.000GB
crash_time  0.001GB
ded         0.305GB
local       0.000GB
visitors    0.000GB
> use ded;
switched to db ded
> db.flights.ded.find();
> db.ded.find();
>                                                                                                                                           why still no output??

Comment: @PuneetMathur I updated my answer, but I suggest you find a basic MongoDB tutorial or one of the MongoDB University courses.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this utility (http://3t.io/mongochef/) it is easy to use and helpful for those who are new to Mongodb. 
While the answer to your question is the record is not showing through database name.First write db.printCollectionStats() which gives you the collection name. then use the collection name to show the data.
Example
db.printCollectionStats() will give you 
xyz
then write 
db.xyz.find()

Comment: > db.ded.find();
    > db.printCollectionStats();
    > no output why?

Comment: which utility you are using?

Comment: See here there is no output for all these statements?? I am not feeling good about mongodb when data is there and showing up ??                                                > db.ded.find()
> db.flights.ded.find();
>                                                                                                                                     No Output to the above why?? Anybody know what is the problem with MongoDB here??

Comment: mongo utility default one

Comment: No doubt Mongodb is best database platform the issue is you are inputting wrong query. It is recommeded to you to use (http://3t.io/mongochef/). and also make sure that you have started mongod.exe from bin folder of mongodb

Comment: Its is gui and you can view data by just one click. Import and export data easily.

Comment: mongod is already running and listening to mongo there is no problem.

Comment: MongoChef is even more hopeless there is no way to see the Document Data only the schema that is so bad..

Comment: Its not the fault of mongod or mongochef then bro. You should need to get some tutorials  on it first.